# Administrator, mass password change

Tags: windows, administrator

my company hired new IT admin and we agreed to set up new admin password. How to change it via script or other way because logging to someone else via remote desktop takes too much time. Obviously i got password to login as Administrator.

I don't have AD yet.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: What environment are you in? How is the network setup? Can you push anything to all users without AD or a VPN?

Comment: Yes, i can push sth to all users via network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change a password for a user account using the `net user` command:

```
net username newpassword
```

So, to change the administrator password:

```
net administrator newpassword
```

You can read more about the `net user` command on [Microsoft's website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394).

---

If you need a way to remotely run that command on your workstations, you can use [Psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). You haven't really given any detail on your environment, so I'm assuming it's just a bunch of networked local PCs.

You would need to create a script to run it remotely on each workstation. Just as a possible example:

```
psexec.exe \\computer1,computer2,etc -u Administrator -p currentpassword net user Administrator newpassword
```